# How to configure pfsense to NAT servers?

Tags: ssh, networking, firewall, http, pf

How can I configure `pfsense` so it will NAT servers so they can be accessed outside of the company? I tried to play around with the NAT settings, but didn't get anywhere. I want to be able to access them remotely using HTTP, SSH, and RDP if I can.

Comment: On a side note, you should not open RDP to the internet. Consider using a VPN to connect to the local network instead. There are tutorials for doing this using pfSense.

Answer (score 6):

This is commonly referred to as "port forwarding". Here is a snippet from the official documentation:

1. Go to the Firewall menu, select NAT, then click on the Port Forward tab.
2. Click on the + icon at the top or bottom of the screen.
3. Choose the Interface for the port forward (likely WAN) and if needed, pick a virtual IP address from the External Address drop-down.
4. Enter your forwarded port in the External Port range box(es)
5. Enter the internal IP address you'd like to send that port to in the NAT IP box.
6. Fill in a local port if it differs from the external port.
7. Check the Auto-add a firewall rule checkbox
8. Click Save which will return you to the Port Forward NAT screen, showing you all the NAT entries.
9. Finally, click Apply Changes - wait a few seconds and test.

Source: http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/How_can_I_forward_ports_with_pfSense%3F

If you are still having problems getting this to work properly, see the [Port Forward Troubleshooting](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Port_Forward_Troubleshooting) doc.